# How to reomove additional text from received email body

Tags: php, html, parsing, email, header

```
--0-1330476969-1311932572=:51625

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii


this is the body of the msg
--0-1330476969-1311932572=:51625
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<html><body><div style="color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:times new roman, new york, times, serif;font-size:12pt"><div><span></span></div>this is the body of the msg<br><div style="font-family: times new roman, new york, times, serif; font-size: 12pt;"><div style="font-family: times new roman, new york, times, serif; font-size: 12pt;"><br><br></div></div></div></body></html>
--0-1330476969-1311932572=:51625--
```

I am working on a forum and when inserting email data into database. Things working fine except the body of received emails having some extra text as above mentioned. Can somebody help me how I can retrieve orignal body text of the email.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual content of the email message, sent in two parts -- one plain-text part for mail agents preferring or only supporting plain text, and one HTML part for those which support and prefer HTML messages. You can use any MIME parser to extract the content.

Comment: Thanks All specialy @Delan. MIME Parser Worked fine for me.

Comment: Not a problem; I'm happy to help. If you feel that this answer is appropriate and solves your issue, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regular Expression to select everything you require from within the `html` or `body` tags as you require.

Comment: Regular expressions are a bad idea for parsing MIME content.

Comment: @Delan - please elaborate - given the above example I think a regex will be just fine.

Comment: MIME has a complex syntax, and for the same reasons as those for HTML, should be parsed with a dedicated parser and not a regex that may work, but would be fragile.

Answer (score 0):

If your server doesn't have the required libraries, you could use something like https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser